# Symbolic Link Edits and differences to hard link

Tags: linux, bash, git, symlink, ln

I just created a symlink to a directory using:

```
ln -s /path/to/real/ link
```

1 - If I then `cd` into `link/` will any changes I make in there be reflected in the original directory?

2 - Additionally, the source directory is a git repo, so can I do the git commands from the symlink'ed directory?

3 - These answers and any general explanation about the differences between sym/hard links (or `ln` in general) would rock.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a Unix question, not a programming question.

Comment: For the first question: yes, any changes will reflect on the original directory. For the second one, look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `cd link/`, your current directory becomes `/path/to/real` and any changes you make in the directory are in 'the real directory'.

Beware of `cd -L` vs `cd -P` — see POSIX on [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) — and similarly with [`pwd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html).

Comment: Okay, cool. The only reason I was unsure is because pwd doesn't show this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links work just like another name for the original directory. They are different from hard links because if you replace the original file with a new one of the same name, the symbolic link points to the new file. A hard link would still be linked to the original file, no matter what name it had.

A symbolic link can "dangle" which means that it's target is no longer there. A hard link cannot.

A directory cannot be hard-linked. In the past that was allowed but it creates the possibility of directory loops, and this is a bad thing.

Yes if you `cd symlink` you can do anything that you want, just as if you were in the actual directory, because you are in the actual directory. Your shell, depending on its configuration settings, will allow you to think you're in the symlink named directory, but all of the operating system functions will return the actual directory names.

Comment: Hard links to directories are really ancient — they were in 7th Edition Unix (but not encouraged), but I'm not sure how much longer they lasted.  Possibly into SVR4, though I suspect not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The horror stories lived on in tales told by ancient grizzled TAs (they must have been 24!) around the flickering fluorescent lights of undergraduate computer labs.